# How to parse nested JSON with python

Tags: python, json

I am very new to python and not a developer. I am trying to figure out a way to parse a nested object.

Example partial JSON

```
{
      "id": 28,
      "url": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/devices/28/",
      "name": "q2",
      "display_name": "q2",
      "device_type": {
        "id": 20,
        "url": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/device-types/20/",
        "manufacturer": {
          "id": 15,
          "url": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/manufacturers/15/",
          "name": "Zyxel",
          "slug": "zyxel"
        },
        "model": "GS1900",
        "slug": "gs1900",
        "display_name": "Zyxel GS1900"
      },
      "device_role": {
        "id": 4,
        "url": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/device-roles/4/",
        "name": "Access Switch",
        "slug": "access-switch"
      },
      "tenant": {
        "id": 3,
        "url": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/tenancy/tenants/3/",
        "name": "NB-TEST",
        "slug": "nb-test"
      },
      "platform": null,
      "serial": "",
      "asset_tag": null,
      "site": {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/sites/1/",
        "name": "COD",
        "slug": "cod"
      },
      "rack": null,
      "position": null,
      "face": null,
      "parent_device": null,
      "status": {
        "value": "active",
        "label": "Active"
      },
      "primary_ip": {
        "id": 301,
        "url": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/ipam/ip-addresses/301/",
        "family": 4,
        "address": "172.31.254.241/24"
      },
      "primary_ip4": {
        "id": 301,
        "url": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/ipam/ip-addresses/301/",
        "family": 4,
        "address": "172.31.254.241/24"
      },
```

I am trying to extract primary_ip "address" and site "name". I can grab the outer objects but how do I then iterate to get inner objects?

```
response2 = requests.get('https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/devices', headers=headers) 
device = response2.json() 
for result in device['results']:  
x=result.get('name')  
y=result.get('primary_ip')  
z=result.get('site')  
print(x,y,z)
```

Example output

```
q1 {'id': 302, 'url': 'https://master.netbox.dev/api/ipam/ip-addresses/302/', 'family': 4, 'address': '172.31.254.254/24'} {'id': 1, 'url': 'https://master.netbox.dev/api/
dcim/sites/1/', 'name': 'COD', 'slug': 'cod'}
```

Comment: `y=result.get('primary_ip')['address']`

Comment: Thanks - that actually worked for site "name" but not IP. I now get this error--More--Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Netbox-python", line 30, in <module>
    y=result.get('primary_ip')['address'] 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: There are None values for the address field in some objects.

Comment: Read up on dictionaries and the .get method of such. What you have is just a nested dictionary from the JSON returned by requests. TL;DR: `y=result.get('primary_ip', {}).get('address')`.

Comment: Thanks Justin - that last suggestion didn't work. I will continue reading but just so you know I now get the error     y=result.get('primary_ip', {}).get('address')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: You must have missed the `, {}` part. Look again at my comment carefully.

Comment: Yes it is included. In the error the full syntax is shown for what I have.

Comment: Well, then you'll need to post a [mre] so that we can help you further. As it is, the code you posted won't run as, for one, `headers` is undefined. At least show us the output of `print(response2.text)`.

Comment: If you're getting the AttributeError from the code I posted then apparently, `result` is None as the 2nd `.get(...)` uses the default `{}` which is not `None`.

Comment: device = response2.json()
for result in device['results']:
 if result is not None:
  x=result.get('name')
  z=result.get('site')['name']
  y=result.get('primary_ip', {}).get('address')

Comment: and I think this is where the problem appears - the primary_ip can by null -   },
      "primary_ip": null,
      "primary_ip4": null,
      "primary_ip6": null,
      "cluster": {
        "id": 7,
        "url": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/virtualization/clusters/7/",
        "name": "Test"
      },